# Turning a 5.1 .mkv into 2.0 or 2.1

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, audio-conversion

Is it possible to turn a mkv file that only has 5.1 into a a 2.0 or 2.1 (or maybe just add 2.0 and 2.1 as an additional sound track) without touching anything else. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a aac -ac 2 output.mkv
```

- `-map 0` [map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) **all** streams instead of relying on the default stream selection which only includes 1 stream per type.
- `-c copy` [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy).
- `-c:a aac` use the encoder named *aac* for all audio.
- `-ac 2` make all audio stereo.

Comment: not only did it works, explains the command too. nice.

Comment: Wait, what happens if you don't add `-map 0`?

Comment: I cant seem to be able to leave 1st track alone (already stereo), and only encode the 2nd track down to 2CH, also cant seem to be able to set the bitrate.